# if $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}x^p\mathbb{P}\{|\xi|>x\}=0$for $p>0$ then $\mathbb{E}|\xi|^r<\infty$ for all $r < p $.

Tags: probability

**Question**

Show that if $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}x^p\mathbb{P}\{|\xi|>x\}=0$for $p>0$ then $\mathbb{E}|\xi|^r<\infty$ for all $r < p $. Give an example showing that for $r=p$ it is possible that $\mathbb{E}|\xi|^p = \infty$

**Know**

$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}x^p\mathbb{P}\{|\xi|>x\}=0 \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}x^r\mathbb{P}\{|\xi|>x\}=0$ for $r < p$

$\mathbb{E}|\xi|^r<\infty \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{x\to \infty}x^r\mathbb{P}\{|\xi|>x\}=0$

Any hints on how to prove the exercise will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property follows from the fact that for a non negative random variable $Y$,
$$
EY^r = \int_0^\infty  ry^{r-1}P(Y>y)\,dy.
$$
so in particular
$$
E|\xi|^r = \int_0^\infty  ry^{r-1}P(|\xi|>y)\,dy.
$$
The condition $\lim\limits_{y\to \infty}y^pP\{|\xi|>y\}=0$ implies that
$y^{r-1}P(|\xi|>y) =O(y^{r-p-1})$ from which the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

I find an example:
$P(X>x)={\frac{1}{x\ln x}}{\mathrm{~for~}}x\geq C{\mathrm{~so~}}F_{X}(x)=1-{\frac{1}{x\ln x}}{\mathrm{~and~}}f_{X}(x)={\frac{1}{x^{2}\ln x}}+{\frac{1}{x^{2}(\ln x)^{2}}}.$
$$
 \begin{aligned}
  \text{Then}\quad xP(X>x)& =\frac{1}{\ln x}=o(1).\text{But}  \\
  &E|X|=\int_{x\geq C}\left(\frac{1}{x\ln x}+\frac{1}{x(\ln x)^2}\right)dx\geq(\ln\ln x)|^\infty_{x=C}=\infty.
 \end{aligned}
 $$